# Why is there no stable nucleus with two or more neutrons but no protons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, strong-force

Why is there no stable nucleus with two or more neutrons but no protons?

Answer (score 4):

Two bound neutrons would not really be called a nucleus as there is no way for an atom to form, as the pair would have a neutral electric charge and be unable to bind with electrons in the usual way.

The terms for a two-neutron state is *dineutron*.  This is a resonance state that is very short lived.  It was reported as having been found in [an experiment in 2012](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v5/30), although I'm not aware if this is widely accepted.  It is very difficult to detect the events that indicate such a resonance state existed.  The lifetime of such a state is about $10^{-22}s$ which puts it well below the accepted threshold for being called an element - that's at least $10^{-14}s$.

Comment: But why is it more weakly bound or short-lived than a deuteron?

Answer (score 0):

Without neutrons, the [SEMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#The_formula) for the binding energy $E_B$ for a nucleus of multiple neutrons simplifies to$$E_B=-(a_A-a_V)N-a_SN^{2/3}+\delta_0[2|N],$$where the last term uses an Iverson bracket, i.e. is absent for odd $N$. In megaelectronvolts$$a_A-a_V\approx23.2-15.8=7.4>0,\,a_S\approx18.3,\,\delta_0\approx12N^{-1/2}$$according to the first least-squares fit summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#Calculating_the_coefficients). Regardless of the values you trust, $a_A>a_V$, and $\delta_0$ is too small for $N\ge2$ to achieve $E_B\ge0$ (well, at least some values suggest $N=2$ is only unachievable because we also have to worry about the surface term proportional to $a_S$). So in short, the asymmetry term is too large compared with the volume term.